# Duplicate designators in a panelized design in Altium

Tags: altium, panelize

I am using Altium 21. I am panelizing the design using Place -> Embedded Board Array/Panelize menu in a PCB editor and later output the Pick and Place centroid file from the resulting panelized .PcbDoc. When I do that I get duplicated reference designators in the output centroid file, which the PnP machine can't use. Is there a simple way to make Altium increment the reference designators from one board to another on a panel so that they are unique? I was searching through the documentation and couldn't find anything like this even though it seems like simple feature.

Comment: Can you program your PnP for a single image, and run it multiple times with the coordinate origin moved?